# Pricing tier error with Azure Speaker Verification API

Tags: azure

I get "The Create Profile Operation under Speaker Verification API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier CognitiveServices.S0."

Note it recognizes operation, API and my pricing tier (which marketing page says should work).

Trying to create a profile:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -d '{"locale":"en-us"}' https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speaker/verification/v2.0/text-independent/profiles
```

Result body:

```
{"error":{"code":"401","message": "The Create Profile Operation under Speaker Verification API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier CognitiveServices.S0."}}
```

Expected: something like this:

```
{
  "profileId": "49a36324-fc4b-4387-aa06-090cfbf0064f",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "enrollmentStatus": "Enrolling",
  "createdDateTime": "2015-04-23T18:25:43.41Z",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2015-04-23T18:25:43.41Z",
  "enrollmentsCount": 0,
  "enrollmentsLength": 0,
  "enrollmentsSpeechLength": 0,
  "remainingEnrollmentsSpeechLength": 20,
  "modelVersion": "2019-12-05"
}
```

Comment: These types of questions are best directed to Azure support.

Comment: Funnily enough, Azure support asked me to post it here

Comment: I would ask for my money back in that case. (I am talking about Azure support ticket option in your subscription)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MS Support, to make it work I need to use a key from Speech Service.

So, create a Speech Service and use its key with the Cognitive Service URL above. It works.